# Getting a particular symbol in SymPy

Tags: latex, sympy

I am trying to achieve a symbol for the Greek letter nu followed by a prime superscript. This can be achieved easily using LaTeX:

`$\nu'$`

I tried many variants in SymPy, none of which gave me the right symbol:

```
nuprime = symbols('{\nu}\'')
nuprime = symbols('{nu}{\'}')
nuprime = symbols('nu\'')
nuprime = symbols('$nu\'$')
```

To mention a few. How do I get the symbol I am looking for on SymPy?

**EDIT**
I am using `jupyter qtconsole` with latex printing. I wish to create the nu prime symbol in this environment.

Comment: Do you try `nuprime = Symbol(r'\nu\'')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was googling some `sympy` stuff recently and came across this question which I asked almost 2 years ago. I am better with latex and sympy now, so I can say with great confidence that the most correct way of doing this is :

```
from sympy import symbols
nu = symbols('\\nu^\prime')
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using the word `prime` in the symbol definition (in the string, not the variable name).  Using Python 2 in Jupyter Notebook,

```
from sympy import init_printing,latex,symbols
import numpy as np
init_printing()
nuprime = symbols('nuprime')
display(nuprime)
print(latex(nuprime))
```

displays

[image: nuprime]

If your want it bold, you can display this by also including the word bold in the symbol definition

```
nuprime = symbols("nuprimebold")
```

[image: nuprimebold]

And if you need a subscript, you can use an underscore to indicate the beginning of the subscript

```
nuprime_subscript = symbols("nuprime_subscript")
```

[image: nuprimesubscript]

These postfixes can be combined as needed.

Other accents can also be used.  The ones I am aware of in addition to `prime` are `hat`, `check`, `tilde`, `acute`, `grave`, `dot`, `ddot`, `breve`, `bar`, and `vec`, but I can't find an official source for this, so this may not be comprehensive.  Here is the definition, display, and latex print for Jupyter Notebook with these accents.

```
nuhat,nucheck,nutilde,nuacute,nugrave,nudot,nuddot,nubreve,nubar,nuvec = symbols("nuhat,nucheck,nutilde,nuacute,nugrave,nudot,nuddot,nubreve,nubar,nuvec")
```

[image: nuaccents]

This technique can be used to modify the display and latex output for any uppercase or lowercase letter of the English or Greek alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure in what context you want the symbol to be represented as ν', but for SymPy’s standard display the following works fine:

```
nuprime = sympy.symbols("ν'")
```

This makes use of the following:

- Python 3 has a straightforward Unicode support.
- You can delimit strings by either single or double quotes. Whatever you choose, the respective other character does not need to be escaped.

Comment: i straight up copied what you wrote and it doesnt work for latex printing on my jupyter qtconsole. I can't accept this answer but I will vote up for the attempt

Comment: @user32882: Please edit your question to specify that this is about LaTeX printing.

Answer (score 1):

I have had some success with the following, though I am not completely sure that I am exactly replicating your circumstances:
1) I opened Jupyter QtConsole
2) I inputted the following code:

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(use_latex=True)
nuprime = sp.symbols("\\nu'")
nuprime
```

This produced the symbol I think you're looking for, at least on my QtConsole.